# it seems like that despite importing the right libs and modules, but still pycharm can not recognize the library

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pycharm

```
class Item(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True,) # create a Column object. db,Column takes an argument which shows the type of the Column, here we used db.String() method
price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False,)
barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False,Unique=True)
desc = db.Column(db.String(length=5000), nullable=False)

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.name = kwargs.get('name')
    self.price = kwargs.get('price')
    self.barcode= kwargs.get('barcode')
    self.desc = kwargs.get('desc')
```

So I am trying to create a database using the SQLAlchemy module. for some reason, this does not work. I am a beginner and have tried to find a solution to the best of my ability but none of them actually solved my problem. I get the error below at the time of execution:

```
  File "D:/program_files/PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3/WEB/market.py", line 33, in <module>
    class Item(db.Model):
  File "D:/program_files/PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3/WEB/market.py", line 37, in Item
    barcode = db.Column(db.String(length=12), nullable=False,Unique=True)
  File "D:\program_files\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\WEB\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1471, in __init__
    self._extra_kwargs(**kwargs)
  File "D:\program_files\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\WEB\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1474, in _extra_kwargs
    self._validate_dialect_kwargs(kwargs)
  File "D:\program_files\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\WEB\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\base.py", line 292, in _validate_dialect_kwargs
    "named <dialectname>_<argument>, got '%s'" % k
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'Unique'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: are you sure your are not using an older version of flask ? update flask

Comment: There is a typo in the barcode row. use `unique` instead of `Unique` (all lowercase).

Comment: (venv) D:\program_files\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3.3\WEB>flask --version
Python 3.7.3
Flask 1.1.2
Werkzeug 1.0.1

It is the latest stable version.

Comment: rfkortekaas 7, Thanks for pointing that out. A note was taken.